# Public acceptance of posthumous beheading of Oliver Cromwell?

Tags: united-kingdom

It is quite well documented that Oliver Cromwell's body was exhumed from Westminster Abbey in 1661. The Act of Indemnity, Pardon, and Oblivion was passed on August 29, 1660 and Cromwell's body was exhumed on January 26, 1661 by Serjeant Norfolke. While I do not question any of the dates in the already available resources, I wish to explore if it was really a publicly accepted act. Was there an opposition to the event dated January 30, 1661? Or in other words, is there any note of dissent recorded during that period that proves or disproves this conjecture?

Comment: [The Wikipedia article on this subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Cromwell%27s_head) says it was done at the order of King Charles II. Why is this not sufficient?

Comment: @Steve Bid : Why did the UK Parliament not act?

Comment: @Spencer : It is hard to believe that the Parliament passed an order for exhumation.

Comment: @Suddhasattwa Ghosh The UK Parliament didn't act because it didn't exist. The English Parliament didn't act because they were generally supporters of the king. King Charles II was in a much stronger position of power relative to Parliament than later monarchs would be, so (in this matter at least) he could do what he liked.

Comment: Until the Glorious Revolution, Parliament was subordinate to the King.

Comment: Cromwell's post-execution head was stuck on a poll outside Westminster Hall for 24 years, until Charles II himself died.  This was all about the king getting revenge for the death of his father.